# Expand and collapse a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, if-statement

I have a list of items & they are holding images, each image is 800w x 600 H. The original div height is 800 W x 300 H. I figured out how to expand the div when it is clicked, but i want to know how to collapse it when you clicked it while it is already expanded. Right now i just expands the div even further

```
  $('.expand').bind('click', function() {
  var currHeight = $(this).css('height').replace(/px/,'');
  currHeight = currHeight * 1;
  var newHeight = currHeight + 500;
  $(this).animate({
     height: newHeight
  },1000);

 });
```

any idea on how to create an `if else statement` that would say, IF the div is already expanded then collapse on click, or if the div is collapse, then expand to # of px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect the current height and branch:

```
$('.expand').bind('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      height = $this.height();
  if (height > 500) {
    height -= 500;
  }
  else {
    height += 500;
  }
  $this.animate({
     height: height
  },1000);
});
```

I've done a couple of other things in there. You can use [`height`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) rather than `css('height')` to get the value without units, and no need for the `* 1` trick. I've also done the `$(this)` *once* and reused it, since there are multiple function calls and an allocation involved when you call the `$()` function. (It doesn't matter here, but it's a good habit to get into provided you're not caching it longer than you mean to [via a closure or such].)

Alternately, you can remember that you've done it another way (using the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) feature):

```
$('.expand').bind('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      height = $this.height(),
      expanded = $this.data('expanded');
  if (expanded) {
    height -= 500;
  }
  else {
    height += 500;
  }
  $this.data('expanded', !expanded);
  $this.animate({
     height: height
  },1000);
});
```

Or combine those to store the original height in case it gets influenced by something else:

```
$('.expand').bind('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      height = $this.height(),
      prevHeight = $this.data('prevHeight');
  if (prevHeight) {
    height = prevHeight;
    $this.data('prevHeight', undefined);
  }
  else {
    $this.data('prevHeight', height);
    height += 500;
  }
  $this.animate({
     height: height
  },1000);
});
```

Take your pick!

Comment: this is great, how would i close all other open divs if there are multiple divs?

Comment: @user: For that, I'd probably use a class (instead of the `data` field). Add a class, perhaps "expanded", and then you can readily collapse them: `$('div.expanded').removeClass('expanded').each(function() { [code to restore height on $(this) ] });`

Comment: @goetzs, @T.J. Crowder: and if you can use CSS to set the height (for the expanded/non-expanded cases), then all you have to do is remove the class - then that will automatically affect the height... my answer might make the idea clearer!

Answer (score 2):

I would use CSS to set the height of the div in both original and expanded versions, and then when the div is clicked, toggle a class to change the height:

```
/* CSS for the height */
.expand {
    height: 300px;
}
.expand.expanded {
    height: 600px;
}
```

and then in the click method, just:

```
$(this).toggleClass("expanded");
```

Comment: Every time i try to implement the toggleClass, it doesn't do anything, I have used it before and for some reason i cant get it to work on this, I am using and UL LI not a div

Comment: @goetzs: It's hard to help without seeing the code... but I would: (a) check that your CSS is right (by adding the `expanded` attribute manually in the HTML, and seeing if the element changes size, and (b) using Firebug (or similar) to check whether the attribute is actually being toggled when the element is clicked.

Comment: I got it to change heights, but it doesnt animate, i tried to place it in an animation function but that didnt work, any suggestions    /Toggle Class on Click
    $(".block").click(function() {
        $("li.expanded").addClass("block", 'slow');
     $("li.expanded").removeClass("expanded", 'slow');
     $(this).addClass("expanded", 'slow');
      $(this).removeClass("block", 'slow');
 
    });

Comment: @goetzs: If you need it to animate, you have to use the jQuery animation routines - `toggleClass` is best for situations where you want it things to change shape/colour/etc immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) at the time of the `click` event and [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) the `height` `+=` or `-=` accordingly (something `.animate()` supports), like this:

```
$('.expand').click(function() {
  $(this).animate({ 
    height: $(this).height() > 300 ? "+=500px" : "-=500px" 
  }, 1000);
});
```

Or, use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), like this:

```
$('.expand').toggle(function() {
  $(this).animate({ height: "+=500px" }, 1000);
}, function() {
  $(this).animate({ height: "-=500px" }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Upvoted to repair the infamous silent downvote that really made a dark spot in your profile.

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers with jQ:

```
.click(function(){})
.css({height: "300*1px"}) // Why are you multiplying Anything by ONE?!
```

And you can use

```
if($(this).css("height") == "300px") {
Do stuff
} else { 
Do other stuff
}
```

Edit: But other options above are far better.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Jquery, check the documentation [Jquery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    height: "toggle"
  }, {
    duration: 5000,
    specialEasing: {
      height: "linear"
    },
    complete: function() {
      //DO YOUR THING AFTER COMPLETE
    }
  });
});
```